# .NET MAUI Overriding Window Class Fatal Exception

Tags: overriding, maui, fatal-error

while overriding Window, I came across a fatal exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: MauiContext is null

I was trying to ovveride Window Class so that everytime the app is open or closed I use messenger to notify the base class to logout the user and request verification to login back.

This is my class where I inherit from Window. And in App.xaml.cs I ovveride it and returning MyWindow using as a parameter MainPage.

I think that when App is in the background and then opened again there is an issue. So guidance on how to handle this exception?

```cs
public class Message : ValueChangedMessage<string>

    {

        public Message(string message) : base(message) 

        { 

        }

    }



    public class MyWindow : Window

    {

        public MyWindow() : base()

        {

        }

        public MyWindow(Page page) : base(page)

        {

        }

        protected override void OnStopped()

        {

            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new Message("Stopped"));

        }

        protected override void OnResumed()

        {

             WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new Message("Resumed"));

        }

protected override MyWindow CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)

{

    return new MyWindow(MainPage);

}
```

```
Fatal Exception: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable:  
System.InvalidOperationException: MauiContext is null.

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window.get_MauiContext()

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.AlertManager.Subscribe(Window window)

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.AlertManager.Subscribe()

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window.<>c__DisplayClass206_0.g__OnPageHandlerChanged|0(Object sender, EventArgs e)

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window.OnPageChanged(BindableObject bindable, Object oldValue, Object newValue)

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, BindablePropertyContext context, Object value, Boolean currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, Boolean silent)

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty property, Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes)

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValue(BindableProperty property, Object value, Boolean fromStyle, Boolean checkAccess)

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValue(BindableProperty property, Object value)

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window.set_Page(Page value)

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window..ctor(Page page)

at name.ViewModels.MyWindow..ctor(Page page)

at name.App.CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)

at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Microsoft.Maui.IApplication.CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)

at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.CreatePlatformWindow(Activity activity, IApplication application, Bundle savedInstanceState)

at Microsoft.Maui.MauiAppCompatActivity.OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

at name.MainActivity.OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_(IntPtr , IntPtr , IntPtr )

at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(_JniMarshal_PPL_V , IntPtr , IntPtr , IntPtr )

   at crc64790243dcc0ae3d15.MainActivity.n_onCreate(MainActivity.java)

   at crc64790243dcc0ae3d15.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)

   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)

   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)

   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1534)

   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3439)

   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3632)

   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)

   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)

   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)

   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)

   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)

   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7701)

   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)

   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)

   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)`
```

Comment: I have created a new project and used your code to overrid CreateWindow in the app.cs. The app worked well and didn't meet the error you mentioned.